# Extend fabricjs group with extra properties

Tags: angular, fabricjs

I am using fabric 3.6.3 with angular.

I am extending the fabric objects successfully using this function:

```
    extend(obj, id) {
    obj.toObject = ((toObject) => {
      return () => {
        return fabric.util.object.extend(toObject.call(obj), {
          itemId:  id
        });
      };
    })(obj.toObject);
}
```

Why is this not working with group objects also?
Here is the code for grouping selected objects:

```
 group() {
    if (!this.canvas.getActiveObject()) {
      return;
    }
    if (this.canvas.getActiveObject().type !== 'activeSelection') {
      return;
    }
    const activeObj = this.canvas.getActiveObject();
    activeObj.toGroup();

    const id = this.randomId();
    this.extend(activeObj, id);
    // activeObj.itemId is null here ?!
    this.canvas.renderAll();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This may have some relevance. Although I’m not exactly sure how to interpret it.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/fabric-js-extend-method/amp/